# Matching rownames that are equal to colnames (of a symmetric or asymmetric matrix)

Tags: r, matrix

I'm doing a statistical analyses on distance matrices in R and want to compare distances within individuals and between groups. I have a matrix where some of the colnames are equal to some of the rownames. I want to extract the values where this criteria is met (the problem is getting it to work on a asymmetric matrix). If the code could save a matrix with logical values where the criteria is met it would be great)

An example of a smaller matrix is shown below:

```
       1         2         3         4
1 0.4966143 0.8359290 0.7319204 0.7579902
3 0.7002979 0.8621343 0.5152356 0.7875813
4 0.7406555 0.8371479 0.7103873 0.5530200
```

I want it to end up like this

```
       1         2         3         4
1    TRUE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
3   FALSE      FALSE     TRUE      FALSE
4   FALSE      FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
```

Would be happy if I could do it without any loops, just vectorized code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
out <- outer(row.names(m1), colnames(m1), `==`)
dimnames(out) <- dimnames(m1)
out
#     1     2     3     4
#1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or `rep`licate the rownames and column names to make the `length`s equal and then do a `==`

```
`dim<-`(row.names(m1)[row(m1)] == colnames(m1)[col(m1)], dim(m1))
```

---

NOTE: as @NelsonGon suggested, when we read data (`read.table/read.csv` etc.) as a `data.frame`, the column names can get appended with prefix `X` as these are non-canonical names i.e. starting with number.  To avoid that either use `check.names = FALSE` argument in the `read.table/read.csv` or post process by changing the column names

```
outer(row.names(df), sub("^X","",names(df)),"==")
```

assuming 'df' is the data.frame identifier object

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(list(`1` = c(0.4966143, 0.7002979, 0.7406555), 
                     `2` = c(0.835929,  0.8621343, 0.8371479), 
                     `3` = c(0.7319204, 0.5152356, 0.7103873), 
                     `4` = c(0.7579902, 0.7875813, 0.55302)), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c("1", "3", "4"))
```